# Wait for multiple statements to execute with R2DBC

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I need to execute multiple statement with **R2DBC** but couldn't find useful DatabaseClient#**inConnection*** examples... So my function keeps getting out too early:

```
public Publisher<Person> groupStatements(DatabaseClient client, Person person) {
// yes, I know that's harsh, but hey! so is JPA's @ElementCollection
return client.sql("DELETE FROM persons_address WHERE person = :id")
    .bind("id", person.getId())
    .fetch().rowsUpdated()
    .map(deleted -> {
        // now recreate every relationship
        GenericExecuteSpec statement = client.sql("INSERT INTO persons_address (person, address) VALUES (:person, :address)");
        person.getOfficePlaces().forEach(address -> {
            statement
                .bind("person", person.getId()).bind("address", address.getId())
                .fetch().rowsUpdated()  // there we go AWOL
                .subscribe(inserted -> {
                    // logging here
                });
        });
        return person;  //FIXME wait! need above grouped statements to complete
    });
}
```

NB: I'm using H2 as a backend.
Thanks for any information!

Comment: Dont use a forEach loop, thats imperative programming. Place the list in a Flux.fromIterable, flatmap, remove the subscribe and then collectList on the flux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a proper batch processing technic (here replacing the map/deleted section), but even got stuck because Statement#execute is returning a Publisher with only #subscribe method and I couldn't return from the chain. So I fed the beast with a few gearing

```
//DEBUG I couldn't figure out how to use labels! good enough
private static final String SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO persons_address (person, address) VALUES ($1, $2)";
...
.flatMap(deleted -> {
    if (person.getOfficePlaces().isEmpty()) {
        return Mono.just(person);
    } else {
        return client.inConnection(cnx -> {
            Statement stmt = cnx.createStatement(SQL_INSERT);
            person.getOfficePlaces().forEach(address -> {
                stmt.bind(0, person.getId()).bind(1, address.getId()).add();
            });
            return Flux.from(stmt.execute()).last().map(dontcare -> person);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are multiple SQL statements you need to execute one after the other, simply create SQL script and add multiple queries separated by a `;` and execute them in a single call `databaseClient.sql(sqlScript)`.

Following is the format of the SQL script that you will create and pass it to your `databaseClient.sql(...)`

```
String script = "DO $$ "+
"BEGIN "+

-- your sql statements here

"END $$; ";

databaseClient.sql(script)
```

so your sql script would look something like this;

```
DO $$ 
BEGIN 

CREATE TABLE persons_address (person varchar(255),address varchar(255);
INSERT INTO persons_address (person, address) VALUES ('first', '123');
INSERT INTO persons_address (person, address) VALUES ('second', '456');
INSERT INTO persons_address (person, address) VALUES ('third', '789');

END $$;
```

Comment: That's not relevant, sorry. I couldn't know relational details in advance, in my example.